# how to use @value annotation inside a method to read a a property from property file?

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-3

Can i use @value annotation inside a method to read property?

```
    void method1(){

     @Value("#{AppProperties['service.name']}") String name;
     -------
      -------
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

accessor private for a method variable is unappropriate.

If you look at the definition of @Value annotation, it can only be placed FIELD, PARAMETER or METHOD level.

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Value {
```

So either you declare name as a class attribute or as a method parameter...

Answer (score 7):

no :) you can use annotations to annotate classes, fields, methods and their arguments. but not in methods, since there is no way, to get method- local variables using reflection in order to process these annotations. Use @Value in your field, and read the value from your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use like this:

```
void method1(@Value("${user.name}") String username){
   // Use your value username
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).